# Verify iMessage Support, SMS Support

Tags: ios, sms, imessage, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am using ShareKit. Sending SMS messages uses the MFMessageComposeViewController, with the user seeing the title "Text". I want to change that title to something that is more reflective of what is actually available, which may be SMS or iMessage or both. (For example, I don't want the prompt to say "SMS" if the device doesn't support SMS, but I want it to say SMS if the device does support SMS. If it supports both, the title will reflect that, too.)

Is there a way to determine if iMessage is available and configured? Is there a way to determine if SMS is available and configured?

The devices I want to support are iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad. The iOS versions should be from 4.3 forward.

Comment: Jim, Did you faced any misbehavior of "MFMessageComposeViewController" in ios 6.0 & 5.0 while dismissing the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Can check like

```
Class messageClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController"));

if (messageClass != nil) {
    // Check whether the current device is configured for sending SMS messages
    if ([messageClass canSendText]) {
        //code for sending SMS
    } else {
        //Not configured
    }
}
```